# How do I create a VBA sub that accesses a database, and then use it inside another sub?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-project

I have a piece of code that accesses a database, and repeats itself as the database 'table' where I get info changes.

My idea is to create another sub with this piece of code and each time I need it I would call it inside the 'big' sub.

Variables `Task_Type` and `X_Loop` are the ones that change

```vb
Dim strSQL As String
'Define SQL Query
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM X_Loop  WHERE Sample = '" & Sample & "' AND Task_Type = '" & TaskType & "'"
'Create recordset with defined SQL Query
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open strSQL, conn, adOpenForwardOnly
            
While rst.EOF <> True And rst.BOF <> True
    SetTaskField Field:="Name", Value:=rst.Fields("Task_Name")
    SetTaskField Field:="Task Type", Value:=rst.Fields("Task_Type")
    SelectTaskField Row:=0, Column:="duration", Width:=2
    SetTaskMode Manual:=True
    EditClear Contents:=True
    SelectRow Row:=1
    InsertTask
    rst.MoveNext
Wend
```

Comment: Check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and tell us what you've already tried, what didn't work, and any output/feedback/errors you receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you encounter a problem such as this, and you know that the code you want to encapsulate in a sub has a number of variables that are going to change, then those variables become parameters to your new sub:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   'call the sub wherever you need
   AccessTheDatabase "X_Loop", "My Sample", "My Task"
End Sub

Private Sub AccessTheDatabase(ByVal TableName As String, ByVal Sample As String, ByVal TaskType As String)
   Dim strSQL As String
   Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
   
   strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & TableName & " WHERE Sample = '" & Sample & "' AND Task_Type = '" & TaskType & "'"
   
   Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
   rst.Open strSQL, conn, adOpenForwardOnly
   
   While rst.EOF <> True And rst.BOF <> True
      'do whatever you need
      rst.MoveNext
   Wend
End Sub
```

You should, of course, name the sub something that makes sense in the context of your app.

Comment: Do you not need to clarify which database you're connecting to in ADODB, i.e. the table name not being sufficient and needing something like `FROM hisDB." & TableName"`? (genuine question, I'm rather new to SQL)

Comment: @Notus_Panda You can specify if needed, but it is usually defined in the connection string.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply. I have a doubt in connection to what @Notus_Panda said: Do I have to also include this block inside the AccessTheDataBase sub? Otherwise I'm getting an error when it tries to execute the rst.open line.`Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    With conn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        .Mode = adModeReadWrite
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & File_PRJ_DB
        .Open
    End With`

Comment: @MarcCasas I assumed from your code that `conn` was global and already had an open connection to the DB.  If that is not the case, then yes, you will need to do something like you suggest inside the sub.